# math.h not being included even when it is included in makefile

Tags: c++, c, makefile, automake

I am trying to build SPRO from http://www.irisa.fr/metiss/guig/spro

They use **Automake 1.6.2** to generate the makefile.

My issue is that when I am trying to make the project I am getting the error

`"undefined reference to 'sin' "` etc.

Here is the error image

[image]

This error is due to the fact that math library is not being included with `-lm` flag but `-lm` is present in `makefile.am`

Here is my `makefile.am`

```
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = 1.4 foreign

ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I auxdir

LDADD    = -lm -L. -lspro @sphere_lib@
INCLUDES = @sphere_include@

include_HEADERS = spro.h
lib_LIBRARIES = libspro.a
noinst_HEADERS = getopt.h

libspro_a_SOURCES = system.h spro.h sig.c spf.c header.c misc.c lpc.c   convert.c fft.c

bin_PROGRAMS = scopy slpc slpcep sfbank sfbcep
noinst_PROGRAMS = scompare

scopy_SOURCES = scopy.c getopt.c getopt1.c
scopy_DEPENDENCIES = libspro.a

slpc_SOURCES = slpc.c getopt.c getopt1.c
slpc_DEPENDENCIES = libspro.a

slpcep_SOURCES = slpcep.c getopt.c getopt1.c
slpcep_DEPENDENCIES = libspro.a

sfbank_SOURCES = sfbank.c getopt.c getopt1.c
sfbank_DEPENDENCIES = libspro.a

sfbcep_SOURCES = sfbcep.c getopt.c getopt1.c
sfbcep_DEPENDENCIES = libspro.a

scompare_SOURCES = scompare.c getopt.c getopt1.c
scompare_DEPENDENCIES = libspro.a

SUBDIRS = doc auxdir test
EXTRA_DIST = README INSTALL COPYING CHANGES
```

Can anyone guide me how to fix this issue?

Comment: "undefined reference" is a link-time error not a compile-time error (i.e. it has nothing to do with a header file). Your problem is that `gcc` only checks for needed symbols once, when they are encountered, so linked libraries need to be listed *after* the object file that needs them. (So you need to have `-lm` *after* the object file in the linking line and not after it.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the order of the dependencies (if libA needs symbols from libB then the order should be `-lA -lB`). So it should be:

```
LDADD    = -L. -lspro @sphere_lib@ -lm
```